# How to use Entity Framework raw query with PostgreSQL in .NET Core 5?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core

I am working on a project to switch from SQL Server to PostgreSQL in my .NET 5 application. I have to use raw queries for the existing code. Here are 2 packages I am using:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="5.0.0" />
```

This function works well:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<LoadEntity>>> GetLoadByIdAsync(long id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var entity = await _dbContext.LoadEntities
                .Where(e => e.LoadId == id)
                .ToListAsync();

    if (entity == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return entity;
}
```

However if I use the raw query, it's broken:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<List<LoadEntity>>> GetLoadByIdAsync(long id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     var sqlQuery = $"SELECT * FROM Load WHERE LoadID = {0}";
     var entity = await _dbContext.LoadEntities
                .FromSqlRaw(sqlQuery, id)
                .ToListAsync();
            
     if (entity == null)
     {
         return NotFound();
     }

     return entity;
 }
```

It throws an error:

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "tbload" does not exist
>
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)...

Any idea how to use raw query with PostgreSQL in .NET Core 5? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Error mentions that your Postgres DB doesn't contain "tbload" table. Does this table existed? Check the table in your database and also check the DbContext to see whether the entity is linked to that table and provide the correct name.

Comment: note the `$` in `$"SELECT * FROM Load WHERE LoadID = {0}"` makes `LoadID = 0` always.

Comment: EF doesn't inspect the query string. It's not clear how the exception message originates from the statement you show. Please show the `LoadEntity` class and its mapping.

Answer (score 1):

From your query, you are attempting to query from "Load" table.

```
var sqlQuery = $"SELECT * FROM Load WHERE LoadID = {0}";
```

But the error mentions:

> Postgres DB doesn't contain "tbload" table

This is possible that in your DbContext, you link the `LoadEntity` to the `tbload` table.

Make sure that the respective entity is pointed to the correct table (name) in your database.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<LoadEntity>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("load");

        ...
    });

    ...
}
```

Also, the way you use the `FromSqlRaw` is incorrect and insecure. Currently, you are querying with a number which is fine. Imagine that you have another query that requires to query with string/varchar/nvarchar values, which could lead to SQL injection attacks such as querying user data, deleting, or dropping table/database and you will get a headache.

[Passing parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#passing-parameters)

> However, the FromSqlRaw method can be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, if improperly used. See below for more details.

Would recommend to use the parameterized query.

```cs
var idParameter = new SqlParameter("id", id);

var sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Load WHERE LoadID = @id";
var entity = await _dbContext.LoadEntities
    .FromSqlRaw(sqlQuery, idParameter)
    .ToListAsync();
```